# gradle to maven conversion, resolve wildcard "+" in version name of dependencies of dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dependencies, pom.xml

I have read other questions but they are not exactly my question.

I have set of projects which are currently build using Gradle and I am trying to switch everything to maven,as projects are based on Gradle naturally in versioning of the artifacts wildcard of "+" is used.
I can solve this problem while generating the single pom of "**BaseProject**" and convert:

```
"projectA-1.0.+" --> "projectA-1.0.0"
```

and it works fine. but my problem is that, "*projectA-1.0.0*" itself depends on "*projectC-1.0.+*" , "*projectD-1.0.+*" and "*projectE-1.0.+*" and naturally I get compile error.
the problem is that each project depends on another one and of course it does not look so interesting to edit all other projects.

```
"projectA-1.0.0"--> "projectC-1.0.+"
               \--> "projectD-1.0.+"
               \--> "projectE-1.0.+"--> "projectX-1.0.+" 
                                   \--> "projectZ-1.0.+"
```

is there any possible solution or workaround for this problem?

**Update 1**

here is the picture of my error log, pay attention that these mentioned artifacts are not directly used in my project and I do not have them in my pom file. I think they are dependencies of my projects dependencies.

[image]

**update 2**

here is parts of the pom of the secondary dependency:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>Myartifact</artifactId>
  <version>1808.0.0</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysecondaryartifact</artifactId>
      <version>1805.0.0+</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

versions resolved with "+" and it is not just in this one pom, this problem exists in all dependencies that translated from gradle.

**update 3**

as you can see in the dependency tree, all versions are translated to maven understandable version, and they are understood by maven but only some of them are not being understood by maven.

```
+--- mygroup:myartifact:1808.0.+ -> 1808.0.0
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.6.2
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.6.2 (*)
|    +--- mygroup:mysecondaryartifactA:1805.0.0+ -> 1805.0.0 (*)    Resolves
|    +--- mygroup:mysecondaryartifactB:1805.0.+ -> 1902.0.0 (*)   Resolves
|    +--- mygroup:mysecondaryartifactC:1808.0.+ -> 1907.0.0       Resolves
|    \--- mygroup:mysecondaryartifactD:2.0.+ -> 2.0.0  Does not Resolve --> Missing artifact mygroup:mysecondaryartifactD:2.0.+
|         \--- commons-primitives:commons-primitives:1.0
```

Comment: I cannot really follow you. Do you want to convert all projects to Maven or just some of them? If you reference a project in Maven, Maven reads the POM, whether it comes from Gradle or Maven. So where exactly lies the problem?

Comment: yes I want to convert all projects to maven but as we have many projects I want to do it gradually, for example if I have 50 projects (projectsNo1 to projectNo50)at the moment I  want to convert projectNo35 to maven and test all requirements and then convert all other projects to maven.

Comment: So, if you convert one of the projects to Maven and reference the other projects in the POM, the dependencies are resolved through the respective POMs, not through the build.gradle files. So you should not see any of the `+` there.

Comment: the problem is that in our build.gradle the versions are not definitive and they are mentioned as "projectX-1.0.+" witch uses the latest version of the "1.0" domain.
as you said maven reads the pom but when resolving a dependency it finds out, that dependency  depends on a dependency with version "projectX-1.0.+".  which does not understand what is it. problem is that gradle translates "+" to latest version on the domain but maven looks for "projectX-1.0.+" string in version name in artifact server

Comment: So does Gradle write something like `<version>1.0.+</version>` to the POM it produces? This would be strange.

Comment: yes it does, lemme give a snapshot here

Comment: I have updated the question, you can check it.

Comment: Could you also add the POM where the bad version is defined?

Comment: add or edit I cant get what you mean?  also I can say I cant edit the other pom because if I want to do it I have to create a new version of "projectX" which is not feasible

Comment: I mean that the broken versions like `9.2.+` are probably read from some POM that Gradle created. This POM will be in your local repository. I would like to see that POM in the question to verify whether this is the real problem.

Comment: I am trying to find it , but no clue, do you have any idea what should i look for and how?

Comment: Your project references other projects by `<dependency>`. Each of the dependency tags goes to another POM, which itself has `<dependency>` tags. You can usually press CTRL in Eclipse and click on the dependency to get to the POM of that dependency. Somewhere down the line, you probably have such a version tag `<version>1.2.+</version>`.

Comment: as you can see in the pom I have copied have version resolved like    <version>1805.0.0+</version>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using maven 5.2.1 or higher, there is a task named publishtoMavenLocal which uses version mapper behind the seen and publishing with this version of maven will resolve the actually used version of the plugins in created pom that located in build\publications\mavenjava